# How does docker network work?

Tags: docker

There is something that I don't understand about the process of IPs allocation in the docker network mechanism.
Suppose I run a few containers. Each gets its own IP address - from where these IP addresses came from?
If one of the container listen to a port, and I go to the browser and write the `<IP>:<PORT>` and see the webpage - How does my computer know to resolve that (That this is a local IP address)?

Comment: A container doesn't get a unique IP address, it gets a unique port (based on the `EXPOSE` in the `dockerfile`). Are you asking how your machine knows how to resolve different local applications on different ports?

Comment: They do have unique IP address. running `docker inspect <ID>` can show that under `Networks.IPAddress`.
Maybe I'm missing something..

Comment: It gets a [private IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces). I'm not sure how your computer resolves it. I think it has something to do with [virtual network interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_network_interface) as I see a whole bunch of them when I run `ifconfig`.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the links, I'll check that!

Comment: Keep in mind docker networks have a bunch of modes (EG. `host`, `overlay`, `bridge`) and they probably all work a bit differently. Reading about those modes would probably answer a lot of your questions: https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A full discussion of Docker networking is out of scope here, so I'll just assume from your question you're talking about `bridge` networking (which is the default).

When you start the Docker daemon (`dockerd`) it creates a ethernet bridge network interface on your local machine called `docker0`.

```
 ~ > ifconfig
 docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:42:09:64:a9:dd  
           inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::42:9ff:fe64:a9da/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:11923 (11.9 KB)
```

This can be customized if neccessary but usually defaults are fine.

This is represented in Docker as a network called `bridge`:

```
~ > docker network inspect bridge
 [
 {
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "25191b73563206a321498c0fac55a897de6ba0333d19f0bdc32c78d290b9fedc",
    "Created": "2018-05-07T18:31:08.680222396-07:00",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
]
```

Notice the `inet addr` / `Gateway` are the same. Also notice:

```
"com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0"
```

To answer one part of your question, your container IP addresses are allocated from this subnet (`172.17.0.0/16`) that Docker creates. Now we know some networking stuff has been setup, let's run a container and see what happens.

```
~ > docker run -d -p 7000:5000 johnharris85/simple-hostname-reporter:2
eeba0f9d23bbd3c10ddf61120ce5d7d1ded6db1515fc37725b68eae12ab6c9b5
```

We can see that this container has an ip address on my bridge network:

```
~ > docker container inspect eeb --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress }}"
172.17.0.2
```

In fact, I can use that IP address and the *container* port to hit my app (try `172.17.0.2:5000` in your browser!). However this is not very scalable / dynamic as this IP address could change when my container is restarted. Also I had to do a bunch of stuff to find it.

Instead of having to do that, I am mapping port 7000 on my host machine to port 5000 in my container (this is the port my application is listening on) so I can visit `localhost:7000` in my browser and hit my app (try that too!).

OK great, so what makes the traffic to port 7000 on my machine magically route to port 5000 in my container?

Let's take a look at `iptables`!:

```
~ > sudo iptables -t nat -S
# ... some stuff
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:5000
```

The (most) important line as far as we're concerned here is the one I've left in above. It says "for all traffic *not* coming from the docker0 interface (`! -i docker0`), using the TCP protocol (`-p tcp`), destined for port 7000 (`--dport 7000`) , actually route it to 172.17.0.2:5000 (`--to-destination 172.17.0.2:5000`)". That is a little simplified of course, but essentially what's going on.

Now if you start another container (this time let's bind to host port 9999):

```
~ > docker run -d -p 9999:5000 johnharris85/simple-hostname-reporter:2
ac4df2bd0a961bfa08735d64fa7f6e69f171e7e499fb86d2ecac6cfba350a5d4
```

And do a quick check of it's IP:

```
~ > docker container inspect ac4 --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress }}"
172.17.0.3
```

Now `iptables` again:

```
~ > sudo iptables -t nat -S
# ... some stuff
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:5000
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9999 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:5000
```

Notice we now have another rule, same structure, this time saying for all traffic to port 9999, send to our new container IP (`--to-destination 172.17.0.3:5000`).

Stop the containers and you'll notice these rules disappear!

IANA networking expert, so some stuff might be a little simplified but hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for the extensive explanation!

Comment: Great explanation

Comment: Excellent explanation