# Why does the client can not connect to localhost:8080?

Tags: docker

I have the following `dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8 as stage0
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY opt /opt
USER root
RUN ["chmod", "-R", "u=rX,g=rX", "/opt/docker"]
RUN ["chmod", "u+x,g+x", "/opt/docker/bin/sapmock"]

FROM openjdk:8
USER root
RUN id -u demiourgos728 2> /dev/null || (( getent group 0 || groupadd -g 0 root ) && useradd --system --create-home --uid 1001 --gid 0 demiourgos728 )
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY --from=stage0 --chown=demiourgos728:root /opt/docker /opt/docker
EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001:0
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/sapmock"]
CMD []
```

as you can see, that exposes the port `8080`.

When I start to run a container from the image as the following:

```
docker run -it  -p 8080:8080 db261ab225b5
Server online at localhost on the port 8080
Press RETURN to stop...
```

The client can not connect through the address `localhost:8080` why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that Rajesh's answer is correct. Although I think it's more likely that your application is just binding to `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` inside the container, and that won't work. Make sure your app binds to `0.0.0.0` inside the container then the port mapping will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But what is the difference between `0.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the loopback interface, it is only accessible from _that_ container. `0.0.0.0` means _all_ interfaces. Your container has an interface on the Docker bridge network with a different IP (usually `172.16.x.x`), so you could have also bound on that, but that's not robust to failures / restarts etc as it will change. Some more detail explanation I have on another answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282792/how-does-docker-network-work/50296284#50296284