# Wait for 0.0.0.0:8080 instead of localhost:8080

Tags: java, scala, testcontainers

In `GenericContainer` class, it exists a method `waitingFor`, that waits for status code `200` as reponse from the server.
I am running a web application in a container and use `0.0.0.0` as host instead of `localhost`. 
When I try to run the `sbt test`, I've got following timeout:

```
[sweetsoft/sapmock:latest] - Could not start container
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [8080] should be listening)
```

I am using the test container as the following:

```
final class MessageSpec extends BddSpec
  with ForAllTestContainer
  with BeforeAndAfterAll {


  override val container = FixedHostPortGenericContainer("sweetsoft/sapmock",
    waitStrategy = Wait.forHttp("/"),
    exposedHostPort = 8080,
    exposedContainerPort = 8080,
  )


  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {

  }


  feature("Process incoming messages") {
    info("As a user, I want that incoming messages is going to process appropriately.")
    info("A message should contain the following properties: `sap_id`, `sap_event`, `payload`")
```

When I would remove `waitStrategy = Wait.forHttp("/")`, then it works fine but with `waitStrategy = Wait.forHttp("/")`
it goes into the timeout.

How to tell the `Testcontainer` to listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of the `localhost`? 
I have described the problem with the localhost here: [Why does the client can not connect to localhost:8080?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201718/why-does-the-client-can-not-connect-to-localhost8080/56201938?noredirect=1#comment99027626_56201938)

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a routable address. As correctly commented on your previous Q, the canonical (v4) address of localhost/loopback is 127.0.0.1 (although all of 127/8 is reserved for it), but to connect to (or test) it from _outside_ you need to use the actual address assigned to its interface. A _server_ normally binds to 0.0.0.0 to allow it to _receive_ connections on all actual (v4) addresses, but each connection uses one of the actual addresses and NEVER 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 but what do I have to do?